# How do I install glusterfs-server using rpm on Oracle Linux 9?

Tags: linux, installation, rpm, glusterfs

I have to install glusterfs-server using rpm on oracle linux 9.
I just found how to install glusterfs-server on other linux distributions.
But, I can not found any solution for oracle linux 9.

- Oracle linux 8 : https://docs.oracle.com/en/learn/gluster-oracle-linux/#introduction
- Rocky linux 9, Cent OS 9 : https://docs.rockylinux.org/guides/file_sharing/glusterfs/

My customer do not want to compile on servers for security reasons.
So, I have to use RPMs to install.